# rq-scheduler does not pass the job to "worker"(django / redis)

Tags: python, django, redis, schedule

I'm trying to figure out the work of the scheduler `rq-scheduler`. There is a scheduler.py:

```
from redis import Redis
from rq_scheduler import Scheduler
from datetime import datetime
from task import save_exchange_rates

redis_conn = Redis()
scheduler = Scheduler(connection=redis_conn) 

scheduler.schedule(
    datetime.utcnow(),
    save_exchange_rates, 
    interval=10,                  
    repeat=None,                    
)
```

it's a script that writes data to the database, if I run it manually, it works. 
task.py:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'market_capitalizations.settings'
import django
django.setup()
import requests
from exchange_rates.models import Currency

def save_exchange_rates():
    url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'
    repositories = requests.get(url).json()
    for exchange in repositories:
          Currency.objects.create(name=exchange['name'],
                                  price_usd=exchange['price_usd'],
                                  last_updated=exchange['last_updated'],)
```

I installed the modules: rq, rq-scheduler, redis.
([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSNZX.png))

But the scheduler `rq-scheduler` does not transfer the task to "worker".

Tell me, please, what am I doing wrong and what is the cause of the problem?

Comment: where is your scheduler.py connected to task.py?

Comment: Oops .. I accidentally erased the decorator.                                              /from django_rq import job/
@job/